# How to assign a webaddress to each item fetch from the database, like www.example.com/datafromdatabase

Tags: php, database, get, directory, webaddress

I want to fetch data from the database and assign it to a web address base on it id. For example if I fetch 5 data from database I want to assign those data to a web address without using Get method.

Just like this `www.example.com/datafromdatabase` instead of this `www.example.com?id=datafromdatabase`. I have seen many forum site using the "/" but I only know the get "?" method.

Comment: this is called "url rewriting", so search for "url rewrite" or "url rewriting". For Apache HTTPD this is usually done with .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for rewrites in this situation, for Apache you will want to use [rewrite rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

For nginx you also want to use [try_files](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files):

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?id=$uri;
```

Both of these will convert the `/directory` to `index.php?id=directory` if the file doesn't exist which will allow images and such to still be served as normal and only rewrite things which aren't files or directories.

Comment: Thank you very much sir i appreciate your response.. pls i still need more enlighten on this rewrite things this is my first time f seen something like this... Can this function convert a get method to directory in web address. what i mean is that i don't want get method to show in the client browser. I want it to display as if it is a directory Just like this www.example.com/datafromdatabase instead of this www.example.com?id=datafromdatabase . Thank as as i expect your answer...